# Retrieving the unique device ID of Microsoft Surface

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am developing an application for Windows 8 and I am testing it on Microsoft's Surface. Does any one know how I can retrieve the unique device ID of Surface?

Just like we do for Windows Phone by retrieving its unique device id using `Microsoft.Phone.Info` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null).Id` converted to string, details at http://coding.kulman.sk/how-to-uniquely-identify-a-windows-8-device/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the closest thing you'll find (for Windows Store apps) is the [ASHWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx), which isn't device specific but rather app+device specific. There are a number of options you can provide in terms of weighting the different factors that comprise the ASHWID.

Comment: How can i deploy applications on windows surface tablet for side loading without using the Power shell procedure?

Comment: How can i deploy applications on windows surface tablet for side loading without using the Power shell procedure?

Comment: for enterprise scenarios there are additional options (Windows 8 Enterprise and side-loading keys available via volume licensing agreement), but otherwise the developer account is needed, which is what the PowerShell procedure facilitates

Comment: is there any other way other than PowerShell procedure for developers?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, unless you give them your source and they load up Visual Studio themselves.  What's the reluctance to using the PowerShell procedure?  It's not a mechanism for distributing the app, just for sharing for testing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

EasClientDeviceInformation esClientDeviceInformation=new EasClientDeviceInformation();
var localDeviceID= esClientDeviceInformation.Id;

Happy Coding:)