# How to get Windows 8 Surface (Tablet) Unique ID

Tags: windows-store-apps

How do I get the Windows Surface unique Device ID?.

I tried the below API but device ID is changing based on Bluetooth settings:

```
HardwareIdentification.getPackageSpecificToken(nonce)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the unique device ID of Microsoft Surface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913579/retrieving-the-unique-device-id-of-microsoft-surface)

Answer (score 2):

As answered [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913579/retrieving-the-unique-device-id-of-microsoft-surface)

```
Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null).Id
```

converted to a String will work to get the ID. Not sure if this is best practice, but it works nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Above API will not help us bcz sometimes this API returning different ID based on Hardware settings. 

I needed to pass the unique device id(Like Mobile IMEI number) to web server.

Do we have anyother API?

Comment: @Pradeepdevendran as Alex K. mentioned, you can parse out the parts that change, and keep the ones that will always remain unique to a specific device. You could always try contacting Microsoft as well and see what they have to say on the matter.

Comment: Whenever I changes the Bluetooth settings above API gives the different   Device ID.

Answer (score 2):

The ID is designed to change if certain system characteristics differ, you can parse out the members you wish to ignore.

> However, the ASHWID changes if the hardware profile of the device
>   changes, such as when the user unplugs a USB Bluetooth adapter. The
>   back-end cloud service can verify the ASHWID and compare it with
>   previously reported values. Though the ASHWID varies, it can be parsed
>   to detect if the variance was simply due to a minor change such as an
>   addition of memory to the system

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx

Comment: I need unique ID which should not be changed at any case like IMEI number in windows phone